# How to redirect to a JSP file from Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm a beginner and am trying to understand how to re-direct to a JSP file from a Servlet.  My Servlet "generates" a result after receiving replies from a current JSP file and with that I result I want to pass it to a different JSP file.  I understand that there is a line of code:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/upload.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

But do I create a separate method for that and call it in the doGET?

Comment: You call that method directly in your `doGet/doPost/doPut/etc.`

Comment: Put it as the last line (more specifically, where you want to redirect from) of doGet method. Basic idea is your controller's logic end and you want to redirect now, place it there.

Comment: call it in the doGet; a one line function with no surprising code seems not needed. Also it is a stop, afterwards a return should follow.

Comment: Please go through some Hello World tutorials first to grasp the basic concepts. You can find a sane one in our servlets wiki page which you can find by hovering the `[servlets]` tag which you placed on the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Comment: Well it is not a `redirect`, it is `forward`ing, you shall know that `redirect` has special meaning in Servlet API. And yes, you shall store your computed data in request scope (by calling `request.setAttribute(?, ?)` method), and then access those values in your JSP.

Answer (score 4):

you can do

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/upload.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

even though you created a `method` seperately you need the `request` and `response` object to the `method`.

I am heavily recommending  the  official docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

and the [**pictorial**](http://www.javatpoint.com/requestdispatcher)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version 3.0 with annotations the redirects are very simple.

Suppose you have a User class (Strings fullname and Username with setters and getters) and UserDAO class that deals with database manipulation .
Suppose this is your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user_list")
public String users(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    //some function to verify access
    boolean authorized = client.getAccess(); 
    request.setAttribute("authorized", authorized);

    if (authorized)
    {
        List<User> users = UserDAO.geUsers();

        request.setAttribute("users", users);
        return "user_list";
    }
    else
    {
        return "access_denied";
    }
}
```

Then you can redirect from any location using the following syntax

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add_user(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)
{

    boolean authorized = client.getAccess();
    if (authorized)
    {
        User user = new User();

            user.setUserName(request.getParameter("username"));
            user.setFullName(request.getParameter("fullname"));

        if (UserDAO.saveUser(user))
        {
            return "redirect:/user_list";
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "access_denied";
    }
}
```

The redirect:/user_list will return updated user_list (eg if you were inserting to db your
changes will be reflected).

Btw: you can drop the .jsp and path in your controller if you add few lines to  your xml:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/

Have a look at those tutorials:

http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-3-mvc-tutorial

http://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-tutorial

Comment: Sorry, somehow I thought I read you were using Spring MVC, therefore I used it in my answer.

Comment: It is not redirecting using Spring MVC, it is `forward`ing, if you want to re redirect using Spring MVC, you shall return `redirect:url` in your controller methods!

Comment: It is redirecting, the url is shortened in the xml which I mentioned in the post above (the link to the tutorial). It looks like this: index.prefix = /WEB-INF/jsp/  
index.suffix =.jsp etc.  The "user_list" is the relevant part of the url (since all of them have common prefix and suffix)